# Pandas: Remove Column Based on Threshold Criteria

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have to solve this problem:
Objective: Drops columns most of whose rows missing
**Inputs**:
1. Dataframe df: Pandas dataframe
2. threshold: Determines which columns will be dropped. If threshold is .9, the columns with 90% missing value will be dropped
**Outputs**:
1. Dataframe df with dropped columns (if no columns are dropped, you will return the same dataframe)

[Excel Doc Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZIEK.png)

I've coded this:

```
class variableTreatment():

    def drop_nan_col(self, df, threshold): 

        self.threshold = threshold
        self.df = df
        for i in df.columns:
            if (float(df[i].isnull().sum())/df[i].shape[0]) > threshold:
                df = df.drop(i)
```

I have to have "self, dr, and threshold" and cannot add more. The code must pass the test cases below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_excel('CKD.xlsx')

VT = variableTreatment()

VT

VT.drop_nan_col(df, 0.9).head()
```

When I run VT.drop_nan_col(df, 0.9).head(), I cannot change this line of code, I get :

```
KeyError: "['yls'] not found in axis"
```

If I change the shape to have 0 instead of 1, I don't think this is correct for what I'm doing, I get:

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Can anyone help me understand how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change from

`df = df.drop(i)`

to

`df = df.drop(i, axis=1)`

So you account for columns instead of rows, which is the default option. See here for the same error https://stackoverflow.com/a/44931865/5184851

Also, to use `.head()` the function `drop_nan_col(...)` needs to return dataframe i.e `df`

Comment: I've tried that as well and get this:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-32d24494dce7> in <module>
----> 1 VT.drop_nan_col(df, 0.9).head()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'head'

Comment: This is a different error, and I think it is related to the fact that you're not returning the dataframe, df. Check my updated answer if it helps.